# Datatables : TypeError: dtSettings is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have implemented data-tables fixed columns on project, the  first (patients_report) data-tables report works very well but the  second(visitation_report)  one fails please advise how can I solve this problem ? 
Below is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>

<link href='http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<link href='http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {


        j(document).ready(function () {
            var table = j('.patients_report').DataTable({
                scrollY: "300px",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false
            });

            new j.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, {
                leftColumns: 0,
                rightColumns: 1
            });
            fc.fnUpdate();
        });



        j(document).ready(function () {
            var visitation_table = j('.visitation_report').DataTable({
                scrollY: "300px",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false
            });

            new j.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(visitation_table, {
                leftColumns: 0,
                rightColumns: 1
            });
            fc.fnUpdate();
        });


        j('.edit_patient_link').click(function () {


            //get data
            var patient_id = j(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="view_patient_id"]').val();

            j.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reports/get_patient_reports_details/" + patient_id,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    j('#edit_patient_id').val(response[0].patient_id);
                    j('#edit_title').val(response[0].title);
                    j('#edit_phone_no').val(response[0].phone_no);
                    j('#edit_inputFirstName').val(response[0].f_name);
                    j('#edit_inputSurName').val(response[0].s_name);
                    j('#edit_inputOtherName').val(response[0].other_name);
                    j('#edit_dob').val(response[0].dob);
                    j('#edit_gender').val(response[0].gender);
                    j('#edit_maritalstatus').val(response[0].marital_status);
                    j('#edit_nationalid').val(response[0].identification_number);
                    j('#edit_email').val(response[0].email);
                    j('#edit_address').val(response[0].address);
                    j('#edit_residence').val(response[0].residence);
                    j('#edit_employement_status').val(response[0].employment_status);
                    j('#edit_employers_name').val(response[0].employer);
                    j('#edit_kinname').val(response[0].next_of_kin_fname);
                    j('#edit_kinsname').val(response[0].next_of_kin_lname);
                    j('#edit_kinrelation').val(response[0].next_of_kin_relation);
                    j('#edit_kinphone').val(response[0].next_of_kin_phone);
                    j('#edit_family_number').val(response[0].family_base_number);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });

        });


        j('.view_patient_link').click(function () {


            //get data
            var patient_id = j(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="view_patient_id"]').val();

            j.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reports/get_patient_reports_details/" + patient_id,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    j('#view_patient_id').val(response[0].patient_id);
                    j('#view_title').val(response[0].title);
                    j('#view_phone_no').val(response[0].phone_no);
                    j('#view_inputFirstName').val(response[0].f_name);
                    j('#view_inputSurName').val(response[0].s_name);
                    j('#view_inputOtherName').val(response[0].other_name);
                    j('#view_dob').val(response[0].dob);
                    j('#view_gender').val(response[0].gender);
                    j('#view_maritalstatus').val(response[0].marital_status);
                    j('#view_nationalid').val(response[0].identification_number);
                    j('#view_email').val(response[0].email);
                    j('#view_residence').val(response[0].residence);
                    j('#view_employement_status').val(response[0].employment_status);
                    j('#view_employers_name').val(response[0].employer);
                    j('#view_kinname').val(response[0].next_of_kin_fname);
                    j('#view_kinsname').val(response[0].next_of_kin_lname);
                    j('#view_kinrelation').val(response[0].next_of_kin_relation);
                    j('#view_kinphone').val(response[0].next_of_kin_phone);
                    j('#view_family_number').val(response[0].family_base_number);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });

        });


        j('.delete_patient_link').click(function () {


            //get data
            var patient_id = j(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="view_patient_id"]').val();

            j('.input_patient_id_delete').val(patient_id);

        });





    });
</script>
<style>
    /* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
    th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see clearly what is the problem with your code. But I assume that is in first part, so put everything in single document ready event. Like this :

```
j(document).ready(function () {
     var table = j('.patients_report').DataTable({
         scrollY: "300px",
         scrollX: true,
         scrollCollapse: true,
         paging: false
     });

     new j.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, {
         leftColumns: 0,
         rightColumns: 1
     });

     table.fnUpdate();

     var visitation_table = j('.visitation_report').DataTable({
        scrollY: "300px",
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging: false
    });

    new j.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(visitation_table, {
        leftColumns: 0,
        rightColumns: 1
    });

    visitation_table.fnUpdate();
    // rest of code
    ...
}); // close document ready event callback
```

There is `fc.fnUpdate();` but I can't find `fc` variable nowhere. That should have been `dataTable` object. I hope this will do the trick. Good luck with project.